# Are there any HDMI Ethernet Channel-enabled consoles?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, ps4, xbox-one, wii-u

Is any of the current or previous generation consoles have HDMI Ethernet Channel-enabled ?

Comment: I have to wonder if this is worth being saved, as I can not see how this would be a useful question to other users, in the future.

Comment: @Timelord64 There are questions about the capabilities of arcade machines. Believe it or not, this is one of them.

Comment: The point is, your asking what consoles have a certain feature. As I feel it falls under game ID, it is clearly off topic. I do not see how this would be of benefit to future users, to warrant further discussion in how this could be cleaned up. I do apologize, the comment thats suppose to appear is more informative, but I realise I clicked on the wrong close reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not only does no video game console ever made support [HDMI Ethernet Channel](http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/hec.aspx), as near I can tell no consumer device of any sort supports it. It's a essentially stillborn part of the HDMI specification. It doesn't look like it will ever see a practical implementation.